# Self or not Self in Widgets

Tags: object, tkinter, widget, self

I run the Codes "With Self" and "Without Self" and the result is the same. Most developers prefer the "With Self" Why? What is the difference? Thanks!

```
# Without Self
import tkinter as tk    
    class MyApp():
        def __init__(self, root):                
            w = tk.Label(root, text="Hello!", font = "Arial 36", bg='yellow')
            w.pack()        
root = tk.Tk()
myapp = MyApp(root)        
root.mainloop()


# With self
import tkinter as tk
class MyApp():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.w = tk.Label(self.root, text="Hello!", font = "Arial 36", bg='yellow')
        self.w.pack()    
root = tk.Tk()
myapp = MyApp(root)    
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: try to add an image to your label, with and without self. Or try to use `print(myapp.w)`. What you are asking for is a really basic python programming and the context decides what you want to use for what. Do a research on *scopes*.

Comment: Try accessing the label inside another function inside your class (a method)

Answer (score 2):

### **Self or not Self?**

Classes or no classes? Functions or no functions?

There is in my *opinion* no really simple, short and straightforward answer to your question. It is a matter of preferences and a matter of what one considers to be a good programming style.

Usage of classes is not strictly necessary for programming `tkinter` applications and I personally prefer whenever it makes sense to avoid the overhead required for coding classes. There is a good reason behind why stackoverflow tries to eliminate questions asking for opinions or preferences. This helps to avoid unnecessary vivid discussions and **Style Wars**.

The Python code below demonstrates that it is possible to configure a `tkinter.Label` without prior saving a reference to it in a class `self.` variable. This is possible because `tkinter` itself stores all of the information about created and still existing widgets and objects. The comments *Try accessing the label inside another function of your class (a method) [without self]* are maybe a tiny bit misleading as they assume that this is not possible and make the difference between **self or not self**.

In the code below along with **self or not self** are two more cases of programming style covered: no function or class at all, and no class but functions. Label modification after its creation is there only to help understanding tkinter and classes:

```
import tkinter as tk    
# No class or function. 
#         Down to  FIVE (5) lines of code:  
root = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(root, text="Hello!", font = "Arial 36", bg='yellow').pack()
root.geometry('800x128')
root.winfo_children()[0].config(text="No class/function:  5 lines")
root.mainloop()

# With a class, but without self. 
#        There are TWELVE (12) lines of code: 
class MyApp_withoutSelf():
    def __init__(self):                
        tk.Label(root, text="Hello!", font = "Arial 36", bg='yellow').pack()
        self.setWindowGeometry()
        self.changeLabelText()
    def setWindowGeometry(self):
        root.geometry('640x128')
    def changeLabelText(self):
        root.winfo_children()[0].config(text="Class no self: 12 lines")
root = tk.Tk()
MyApp_withoutSelf()        
root.mainloop()

# With a class and with self 
#        There are FOURTEEN (14) lines of code: 
class MyApp_withSelf():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.w = tk.Label(self.root, text="Hello!", font = "Arial 36", bg='yellow')
        self.w.pack()
        self.setWindowGeometry()        
        self.changeLabelText()
    def changeLabelText(self):
        self.w.config(text="Class with self 14 lines")
    def setWindowGeometry(self):
        root.geometry('640x128')
root = tk.Tk()
myapp = MyApp_withSelf(root)    
root.mainloop()

# No class but functions.
#        There are ELEVEN (11) lines of code: 
root = tk.Tk()
def setup():                
    tk.Label(root, text="Hello!", font = "Arial 36", bg='yellow').pack()
    setWindowGeometry()
    changeLabelText()
def setWindowGeometry():
    root.geometry('920x128')
def changeLabelText():
    root.winfo_children()[0].config(text="No class but functions 11 lines.")
setup()    
root.mainloop()
```